# Paypal Subcription payment want 3 option?

Tags: paypal, payment, subscription

When user click on subscribe button of paypal, then it will redirect to paypal site, after that it will show 2 option which are:

1: login with paypal
2: i need to create a paypal account and below showing credit card form

and my requirement is to show 3 option.

1: Login with Paypal account.
2: If no paypal account then create paypal account.
3: no need paypal account, then payment through credit card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create subscriptions without requiring users to have a PayPal account.
However, it's not available for regular Website Payments Standard; you'll need to purchase an add-on service called '[Enhanced Recurring Payments](https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/erp_overview)' (US) or '[Premium Services](https://www.paypal-business.co.uk/premiumservices/index.htm)' (UK).

I believe - from the top of my head - that it's available in the US, UK, Canada and Australia. However, you'd need to double-check those last two with PayPal Sales.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let your users to subscribe (aka recurring payment), they *must* have a PayPal account.

Source: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/How-to-use-PayPal/Subscriptions-is-a-PayPal-account-required/td-p/44420

Answer (score 0):

For recurring payments you can try using [ChargeBee](https://www.chargebee.com), [Recurly](https://recurly.com/), Chargify. These provide credit card data portability. It is must to have requirement for recurring payment businesses.